# How do you specify an element in angular as a php array []

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to post multiple values in angular on an element using php however when I use the notation of [] angular errors out.  How do I specify this element to be an array so it can be processed serverside.

```
ng-model="form_values.people[]"  //This errors out.

Syntax Error: Token ']' not a primary expression at column 18 of the expression


$http({
    url: "../ajax/my_script.php",
    method: "GET",
    params: $scope.form_values,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
 })
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `ng-model=people[]`. What is this `ng-model` of?

Comment: I have a multiselect. I want to post multiple values for one element.  If I use ng-model="people", on the server-side the variable people will only get the last option selected.  Typically in html if you use [] for an element, php knows its an array and multiple values are being passed.

Comment: Just use `ng-model="people"` for multi-select. It will automatically make it an array.

Comment: How are you posting your values to the server? The use of `[]` applies to the `name` properties of form elements. The syntax used in Angular directives is something completely different.

Comment: I'm posting by using angulars http service and then using the get method and sending my values in the params property.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Here's a plunker with multi-select that sets `ng-model` to an array: http://plnkr.co/edit/HWAMSSXHgqgwG8XUx8kL

Comment: Yes, this works on client side.  However, when using PHP, $_REQUEST['foo'] will only yield the last selected option.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you clarify "post multiple values in angular on an element using php"? Are you trying to do HTTP POST to a php server? If so, shouldn't you be using "POST" and not "GET"?